# Rewrite calls to index.php in redirected subdomain within .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I have two domains currently in my server, one for the main domain (`www.domain.com`) and the other one for the test domain (`test.domain.com`). Each domain points to a folder containing a Joomla installation and within each folder there is the stardard `.htaccess` file that comes with the installation.

The main domain works fine but the test domain does not quite work as expected. If I browse to `test.domain.com` I can see the Home page correctly but if I browse anywhere else (i.e. `test.domain.com/products.html`) I get a 500 error. However, if I append `index.php` after the subdomain it works as expected (i.e. `test.domain.com/index.php/products.html`).

This is the `.htaccess` file in `/public_html` folder:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# pointing www.domain.com to live
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !test.domain.com
ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.domain.com
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/live/
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ live/$1 [L]

# pointing test.domain.com to test
ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} test.domain.com
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ test/$1 [L]

# Add a trailing slash to directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ([^/]+)$ $1/ [L]

# Rewrite any calls to /* to the index.php file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Here is the folder structure in the server:

```
/public_html
    |
    |--/live             <-- www.domain.com
    |     |
    |     |--.htaccess   <-- joomla standard .htaccess
    |
    |--/test             <-- test.domain.com
    |     |
    |     |--.htaccess   <-- joomla standard .htaccess
    |
    |--.htaccess
```

The `.htaccess` files in the `live` and `test` folders have `RewriteBase /live` and `RewriteBase /test` respectively.

I have found several questions regarding subdomain redirection here in stackoverflow and in many other sites but none of them solve this specific issue. Does anyone know what I am missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to put subdomain rules before main domain?
Here's my .htaccess that works fine for real project.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index-test.php [NC,QSA] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php
```

Comment: I put the subdomain rules before the main domain but it did not work. I'm still having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue partly with @witzawitz comment about rearranging the subdomain rules but also by removing `RewriteBase /test` line in the `.htaccess` file in `/test` folder and `RewriteBase /live` line in the `.htaccess` file in the `/live` folder.

This is the solution:

`.htaccess` file in `/public_html` folder:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# pointing test.domain.com to test
ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} test.domain.com
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ test/$1 [L]

# pointing www.domain.com to live
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !test.domain.com
ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.domain.com
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/live/
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ live/$1 [L]
```

`.htaccess` file in `/public_html/live` and `/public_html/test` folders:

```
## I have removed license and unnecessary comments 

# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for something within the component folder,
# or for the site root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to redirect all traffic to your *.example.com/path/to/request into *.example.com/index.php where * is sub domain and/or www or even omitted put below code in public_html/.htaccess:

```
Options + FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /
```

Then, you can access path/to/request via

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```